# Selecting Text in a webview should bring a selection range handlers in android

Tags: android

I have a WebView in my Android application.

When I select a text, the text is copied automatically and the highlighting (selection) disappears.

I want the highlighting to stay and I want a pair of handlers that i can drag to expand the selection range.

Android 2.3. and later does provide this option but I want to implement this on some lower versions. They have somehow mysteriously implemented it on HTC browser. Here is a snapshot of what I exactly need.

[image]

How can I do this on Android 2.2 and lower versions?

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but how did you get those handles and that menu on a web view. I get square handles in the web view on mine. My minimum sdk level is 9 (2.3) and my device is running 2.3.4

Comment: This is on android 2.2... It is the HTC SenseUI doing it...

Comment: Ah. I'm trying to do it in my own WebView subclass in an app. Not working out so well.