# How to programatically / force select text in a WebView (with copy-paste context dialog, Android 7)

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview, clipboard

I have a (HTML) span in a WebView which contains text that is sometimes unselectable. This is for an [open-source Japanese Kanji learning app](https://github.com/xiprox/WaniKani-for-Android), so the text is in Japanese, perhaps that is why long-press selection sometimes doesn't work properly. I don't know. Anyway, what I am trying to do is this:

When the user long-presses any part of the whole span box (where the actual text is centred), I want to **pretend like the user actually long-pressed the text**, so I want to 'android select' the text, which would bring up the copy-paste context dialog too.

I found a way to 'html select' the text [via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/987376/1072869), but this does not trigger an 'android select', i.e. the copy-paste context dialog does not show.

I have searched extensively for a way of selecting text in a WebView through Java ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111844/selecting-text-in-a-webview), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754366/selecting-text-in-a-webview-should-bring-a-selection-range-handlers-in-android), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881824/android-programatically-trigger-text-selection-mode-in-a-webview-on-jelly-bean), especially [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058843/android-how-to-select-texts-from-webview)). That last one seemed promising but most of the question and answers seem nonsensical. I think this is because I am working with Android 7.0, while the answers seem to use a 'Selection Mode' which the latest Android doesn't have.

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, unfortunately no, sorry. I did what I needed to do another way. Good luck!